# How to implement a file tree view folding animation like Sublime's using CSS only?

Tags: css

I'm trying to implement a file tree view, but I have no idea to implement the folding animtation when clicking the folders using CSS only. How could I figure out it?

Comment: :active :focus {do any here}

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend. You'll want to look at using `-webkit-transition` and `ease/ease-in`.

Apply this to your current CSS3 treeview code:

http://candpgeneration.com/toys/CSS3-dropdown-tut.php

Specifically:

> So by now you should have a plain vanilla CSS drop-down menu. Let's add the magic.

Add these properties to the `.navigation ul ul` rule:

```
-webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
            -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
            -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
            -ms-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
            transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
```

And these, to the `.navigation ul ul li` rule:

```
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
            -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
            -o-transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
            -ms-transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
```

Comment: I have google already, and these links doesn't meet my requirement. They only implement the show and hide effect but the animation like Sublime's.

Comment: So implement your own transition/animation.

Comment: That's what I asking...I have no idea... T_T

Comment: @JasinYip Check updated answer. It shows examples of how to apply a folding/animation to dropdown using CSS3.